# Can I rescript a PIC18F microprocessor using the TTL/RS232 lines

Tags: microprocessor

> Can I rescript a PIC18F microprocessor using the TTL/RS232 lines?
>
> Is there any standard program that can monitor the PIC I/O and simply
>   print out the data on screen?

I'm asking this on behalf a friend, so please excuse the lack of details and perhaps wrong tagging. I would really appreciate any improvement suggestions.

Comment: I have tried to rephrase the second question. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: The second question is clear to me, either send the pin status through a UART/serial/somehow to the pc to be displayed, or a logic analyzer.

Comment: @Mahdi Why do you want to sniff/monitor the I/O of an MCU?

Comment: @Roh I'm asking this on behalf a friend. I think he is trying to reverse engineer a legacy hardware but I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question is as @davetweed said, you need a boot loader to do it directly. Or you need a programmer that has serial communication. So PC -> Serial -> Programmer -> Pic.

The second question has three options:

1. Serial communication from the Pic to your pc, via RS232 or a usb-to-ttl cable. You could use a comm/serial port software like Hyperterminal or Putty or similar, and get basic information back and forth. Requires coding the Pic to support this.
2. An external logic analyzer. Something simple like a bunch of leds connected to the pins, or more complex like one connected to a computer. The pc logic analyzer will have software to use with it.
3. The debug/programmer for the Pic. Not sure what the status of Pic programming and debugging is, but if its anything like the msp430, the debugging software can show you the pin, I/O, and register states as well as memory dumps, etc. Depends on your programming software and hardware programmer support.

Answer (score 1):

You can reprogram a PIC (or any other microcontroller) via the UART only if it already has a UART bootloader programmed into it.

The second question is still a little unclear. Are you talking about a program that *runs on the PIC* and monitors its own I/O? If so, what "screen" are you talking about? Otherwise, a program that *runs on the host PC* would need external hardware (e.g., a logic analyzer or "bus pirate" to connect to the PIC pins in question.

Comment: Dave, I decided to accept @Passerby's answer because it has more details and hopefully it will be more useful for others in the future. I still appreciate your time for answering the question. It was really helpful at the moment my friend needed it.